# WebCam Preview and Capture to File (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, directshow, ms-media-foundation

What are the available options for creating applications that allow preview of a webcam and exporting the current webcam image to file?

EDIT: I've since found that MS [Media Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms697062%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) offers similar features to DirectShow that work from Vista upwards. However, while apparently possible, the documentation, samples, and forums don't suggest an *easy* way to perform the above. On the other hand, with DirectShow you can fairly easily merge two of the sample apps to achieve it.

EDIT: Researching available camera APIs I've also found the MS [MediaCapture API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452791.aspx) looks useful but this seems to be only available on windows 8 (and may be limited to managed C++/.net/javascript).

EDIT: DirectShow is supported on the Windows 8 standard desktop (For Metro style applications the video platform is Media Foundation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using directshow. You may have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407269%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You basically found the answers yourself. DirectShow and Media Foundation are the APIs. Neither of the two cover all Microsoft environments: Metro supports a subset of MF, and MF is not available in legacy OSes. DirectShow is presumably easier, more flexible, with more sample code around.